# Using Pagination in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a Spring Boot 1.5.2 project which up till now has been sending lists back to the view. **I would like to use pagination instead of lists**. I began to change the code in the service layer and repository, but it has not been a simple case of changing from `List<T>` to `Page<T>`.

In particular on the service layer I was returning different `List<T>` based on user role and then passing this list to a method that converts to Dto before sending it back to controller.

Spring Boot 1.5.2 appears to use [Spring-data-jpa:1.11](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.11.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html)

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/dashboard/sale")
public String dashboard(@RequestParam(name = "p", defaultValue = "1") int pageNumber, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<SaleDashboard> listSaleDashboard = saleService.getPage(pageNumber);
    model.addAttribute("listSaleDashboard", listSaleDashboard);
    return "dashboard";
}
```

**Service Layer**

```
public List<SaleDashboard> getPage(int pageNumber) {
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGESIZE, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
    List<Sale> listSale = new ArrayList<>();
    if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        listSale = saleRepository.findBySomeProperty(user.getUserDetails().getReportDept());
    }
    if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
        listSale = saleRepository.findByListOfCreatingUser(userList);
    }
    List<SaleDashboard> listSaleDashboard = createSaleDashboard(listSale);
    return listSaleDashboard;
}

public List<SaleDashboard> createSaleDashboard(List<Sale> sales) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    List<SaleDashboard> listSaleDashboard = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Sale sale: sales) {
        SaleDashboard saleDashboard = new SaleDashboard();
        saleDashboard.setSaleId(sale.getId());
        // ETC
        listSaleDashboard.add(saleDashboard);
    }
    return listSaleDashboard;
}
```

In the service layer above I began to use PageRequest but thats as far as I got.

**Repository**

```
public interface SaleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sale, Long> , PagingAndSortingRepository<Sale, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Sale e WHERE e.creatingUser in (:userList)")
    Page<Sale> findByListOfCreatingUser(@Param("userList") List<User> users, Pageable pageable);

}
```

How would I implement a similar service layer but use `Page<T>` instead of `List<T>`?

Comment: Move the `ROLE` logic in the `JPQL`  and use `spring-data` pagination.

Comment: Using [Spring Data Web Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.web), you can define `Pageable` parameter in your controller method. Then pass the same `Pageable` instance to your service layer method and finally add pagination to your [repository methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)